# Docker - host's localhost times out on assigned docker port

Tags: docker, networking

I recently installed a new Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) from scratch on my computer and now I run a Postgres Docker container via,

```
sudo docker run --name oes-dev -p 5440:5432 -d kartoza/postgis:9.6-2.4
```

But, now `curl --verbose localhost:5440` returns,

```
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:5440/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5440 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5440
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I googled for more than half an hour without success. Pretty sure a networking issue (after all, the same image is running on a remote server and I can `curl` that one just fine), but don't have the slightest idea where to start.

Can someone point me in the right direction pls?

Thanks
Nils

**EDIT**
`sudo docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
1beff7b6aaf3        kartoza/postgis:9.6-2.4   "/bin/sh -c /docker-…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5440->5432/tcp   oes-dev
```

**EDIT2** `sudo docker network inspect bridge`:

```
[
{
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "5d3e43f0716aec7c29a56eb7f74e396ac72e010cc760078633549c1901f488cc",
    "Created": "2018-10-11T18:26:52.277074856+02:00",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "1beff7b6aaf32b359fa85901db7efa65c7090117fdde93d81d665231f8e32960": {
            "Name": "oes-dev",
            "EndpointID": "42dab201b145ff71b81e48618ec80cc8124625c89169d8932fb97a150f716e2c",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
]
```

Comment: What's the output of `docker ps`?

Comment: Maybe what's the output of `docker network inspect bridge`? These are random stabs in the dark though, not sure what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @maxm, I appreciate your random stabs! A difference to the same container running on the server: `IPAM.Config.Gateway=172.17.0.1` is missing